# calculating the sum of nodes in a single verticle line of a binary tree

Tags: array-algorithms

For a binary tree i want to  get the sum of all nodes that fall in a single verticle line. I want the sum of nodes in each verticle node

```
             A
           /    \
          B      C
         /  \   /  \
         D   E  F   G
        / \ 
        H  I
```

IF you look at above tee

```
line 0   A  E F   so sum  = A+E+F
line -1  B I      so sum = B +I
line 1   C        so sum = C
line 2   G        so sum = G
```

I implemented following algorithm

```
Map<Integer,Integere> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()
calculate(root,0); 

 void calculate(Node node, int pos){
   if(node==null)
        return ;
  if(mp.containsKey(pos) ){
    int val = mp.get(pos) + node.data;
     mp.put(pos,val);
    }
    else{ 
         mp.put(pos,node.data);
    }

    calculate(node.left,pos-1);
    calculate(node.right,pos+1);

}
```

1. I think the above algo is fine.Can
   any one confirm?
2. Also how can i do it without using
   HashMap,arraylist or any such
   collection datatype of java.One
   method is two is 2 arrays one for
   storing negative indexes(mapped to
   positive) and one for positive
   indexs(right side of root).But we
   dont know what the size of array
   will be.
3. One approach is to use doubly link
   list and add a node on right/left
   movement if necessary. Am not
   getting how can i implement this
   approach? Any other simple/more time
   efficient approach?
4. Is the complexity of the above code
   i imolmeted is O(n)? (am not good at
   analysing time complexity , so
   asking )

Comment: It's completely unclear how "a single vertical line" is defined in the general case of an arbitrary binary tree.

Comment: @Alexey Kukanov  : Please see the example of tree i have given.It describes what a verticle line is.When you move left index is decresed by 1 , when move right incresed by one, so nodes with same index fall in single verticle line.verticle line to which roor belongs has index 0

Comment: how come E and F falls under same vertical line

Comment: Start with verticle line of root.Now to reach F you need to one step right and then one step left.left= 1 right =-1 ,so +1-1 =0, so  index of F = 0 .To reach E -1+1 = 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical sum of a binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646575/vertical-sum-of-a-binary-tree)

Comment: why would you want to compute something like this? What would be the point of computing the sum of the vertical columns of the tree? What are some of the uses of this algorithm? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ code

```
int vertsum(Node* n, int cur_level, int target_level)
{
  if (!n)
    return 0;

  int sum = 0;
  if (cur_level == target_level)
    sum = n->value;
  return sum + 
         vertsum(n->left, cur_level-1, target_level) + 
         vertsum(n->right, cur_level+1, target_level);
}
```

invocation example:

```
vertsum(root, 0, 1);
```

**EDIT:**

After clarifying the requirements, here the suggested code. Note that this is C++'ish and not exactly using Java's or C++'s standard API for lists, but you should get the idea. I assume that `addNodeBefore` and `addNodeAfter` initialize node's data (i.e. `ListNode::counter`)

```
void vertsum(TreeNode* n, int level, ListNode& counter)
{
  if (!n)
    return;

  counter.value += n->value;
  counter.index = level;

  if (! counter.prev)
    addNodeBefore(counter);
  vertsum(n->left, level-1, counter.prev);             

  if (! counter.next)
    addNodeAfter(counter);
  vertsum(n->right, level+1, counter.next);

  return;
}
```

Comment: @dojoBeginner - this is not clear from you problem definition. In this case you indeed need a list of counters. You can use a `map` as you do  or you can optimize the counter access (worth only if the tree is very large) by using 2 counter vectors - for negative and non-negative indices

Comment: I cant use map or any such datatype as mentioned in my post.Can you help me solve it suing a doubly link list?As we move left or right we create/update nodes in link list as at end we have a link lest containing the sum of each vertcile line

Comment: @dojoBeginner - ok, now I've read your question through :) yes, you can solve it with double-linked list of counters, passing the node to the left or right each time you move on the tree. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could visit the binary tree in depth-first postorder, and use an offset to keep track of how far you moved to the left/right with respect to your starting node. Every time you move to the left, you decrement the offset, and every time you move to the right you increment the offset. If your visit procedure is called with an offset of `0`, then it means that the node being visited has the same offset of your starting node (i.e. it's in the same column), and so you must add its value.

Pseudocode:

```
procedure visit (node n, int offset) {
  sumleft = 0
  sumright = 0
  if (n.left != null)
    sumleft = visit(n.left, offset - 1)
  if (n.right != null)
    sumright = visit(n.right, offset + 1)
  if (offset == 0)
    return n.value + sumleft + sumright
  else
    return sumleft + sumright;
}
```

For example, if you call

```
visit(A, 0)
```

you will get the following calls:

```
visit(A, 0) -> E.value + F.value + A.value
  visit(B, -1) -> E.value
    visit(D, -2) -> 0
      visit(H, -3) -> 0
      visit(I, +2) -> 0
    visit(E, 0) -> E.value
  visit(C, +1) -> F.value
    visit(F, 0) -> F.value
    visit(G, +1) -> 0
```

Another example, starting from node `B`:

```
visit(B, 0)
  visit(D, -1) 
    visit(H, -2)
    visit(I, 0) -> here we return I.value
  visit(E, +1)
```

when recursion goes back to the initial call `visit(B, 0)` we have `sumleft = I.value` and `sumright = 0`, so we return the final result `B.value + I.value`, as expected.

Complexity of O(n), because you visit once all nodes of your tree rooted at the starting node.

---

After think about the above algorithm, I realize it has a limitation, which becomes evident when we consider a more complex tree like the following:

[image: tree columns]

In this case `visit(B, 0)` would still return `B.value + I.value`, but this is not the expected result, because `N` is also on the same column. The following algorithm should cope with this problem:

```
procedure visit(node n, int c, int t) {
  sumleft = 0;
  sumright = 0;
  if (n.left != null)
    sumleft = visit(n.left, c - 1, t)
  if (n.right != null)
    sumright = visit(n.right, c + 1, t)
  if (c == t)
    return n.value + sumleft + sumright;
  else
    return sumleft + sumright;
}
```

The idea is essentially the same, but we have now a parameter `c` which gives the current column, and a parameter `t` which is the target column. If we want the sum of the elements in the `B` column, then we can call `visit(A, 0, -1)`, that is we always start our visit from node `A` (the root's tree), which is at column 0, and our target is column -1. We get the following:

[image: tree columns calls]

Therefore `visit(A, 0, -1) = B + I + N` as expected.

Complexity is always O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the tree, because we visit the entire tree with depth-first postorder, and we process each node only once.

---

If we want to compute the sum of every column, we can use the following algorithm

```
procedure visit(node n, int c) {
  if (n.left != null)
    S{c} += n.value;
    visit(n.left, c - 1)
    visit(n.right, c + 1)
}
```

and call once `visit(A, 0)`, where `A` is the root node. Note that `S{...}` in the algorithm is a map whose keys are the columns numbers (..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...) and whose values (at the end of the algorithm) are the sums of the values of nodes in that column (`S{1}` will be the sum of nodes in column 1). We can also use an array, instead of a map, provided that we pay attention to the indexes (arrays have no negative indexes). The algorithm is still O(n), because we traverse the entire tree only once. However, in this case we need additional space to store the sum for all columns (the map, or the array). If I'm not mistaken a binary tree of height `h` will have `2*h + 1` columns.

Comment: @ MarcoS :Your code only returns sum in verticle line 0, i am trying to do it  for all lines

Comment: @dojoBeginner: call `visit(B, 0)` to get the sum of nodes values in the `B` vertical line for the sub-tree rooted at `B`

Comment: @MacroS: In that case we will be visiting same nodes multiple times.For example A will be visited  for call visit(A,0) , visit(B,0), visit(D,0),visit(H,0) ?? In this case time complexity will not be O(n) i guess.Please comment

Comment: @dojoBeginner: if you start with a call to `visit(B, 0)`, then `A` will not be visited, because it's not a child of `B`. So, given a starting node `x`, you visit all the sub-tree rooted at `x` in depth-frist postorder, and each node is visited only once, so complexity is O(n), where n is the number of node in the sub-tree rooted at `x`

Comment: @MarcoS :.As visit(B,0) doesnot add value of A , value returned by visit(B,0) is incorrect

Comment: @dojoBeginner: I think it's correct: I've edited my answer adding the example for `visit(B, 0)`

Comment: @dojoBeginner: I've edited again my answer, because I found out a case where my original algorithm failed. I wrote a variation of the algorithm which should now work for any case, and whose complexity is always O(n).

Comment: @Marcos:I am dojoBeginner(logged in  from a different pc):Your algo is fine.But suppose i make a single call visit(A,0,0).This will return only sum of nodes in verticle line A.Now to get sum of verticle line b i have to make a seperate call visit(A,0,-1).So to get sum of each line i need to traverse entire tree again .So doesn it has complexity 0(n2)??

Comment: @dojoBeginner: computing the sum for all columns in one visit is easy, but we need additional memory space to store the results. I edited my response and added a variation of algorithm that does this. I hope this finally answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? (Inside your node class, assuming getData returns the integer value, hasRight() and hasLeft() are boolean values indicating whether a right/left branch exists and getRight() and getLeft() return the next node in the right/left branch.

```
public int calculateVerticalLine(int numLine) {
    return calculateVerticalLineRecursive(numLine, 0);
}

protected int calculateVerticalLineRecursive(int numLine, int curPosition) {
    int result = 0;
    if(numLine == curPosition) result += this.getData();
    if(hasRight()) result += getRight().calculateVerticalLineRecursive(numLine, curPosition+1);
    if(hasLeft()) result += getLeft().calculateVerticalLineRecursive(numLine, curPosition-1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It will give op only for line no which you pass.I want to do it for all lines

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

    public static int getSum(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
        //Your code goes here.
        if(root==null){
            return 0;
        }
       int leftnodesum=getSum(root.left);
       int rightnodesum=getSum(root.right);

    
    return root.data+leftnodesum+rightnodesum;
    }
}
```