# Vertical sum of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

How to find the vertical sum of a binary tree.

For example,
Consider the binary tree below,

```
                      1
                    /  \
                   /    \
                  /      \
                 2        3
                / \      / \
               /   \    /   \
               4   5    6    7
              / \ / \  / \  / \
             5  9 1  3 6 7 5   5
```

For the above tree, Vertical sum should be calculated as follows,

- Line 1: 5
- Line 2: 4
- Line 3: 2,9,1
- Line 4: 5
- Line 5: 1,3,6
- Line 6: 6
- Line 7: 3,7,5
- Line 8: 7
- Line 9: 5

Output should be:

```
5,4,12,5,10,6,15,7,5
```

Comment: How you are calculating the sum? how its vertical?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please find the vertical lines.

Comment: It's not clear to me how are the vertical lines defined. Could you show it for a tree with one more level?

Comment: Why do nodes 1, 5 and 6 count as being in the same column? Would 5 and 6 still count as being in that column if there were another level in the tree?

Comment: This question is far from clear. Why is line 5 the same as 1,3,6? How did you arrive at "1,3,6"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I don't think this is not a real question. By checking my answer you can see, In all I'll voting to reopen.

Comment: The problem is that the question isn't clear, existing answers nonwithstanding. The question does not specify how to arrive at those vertical lines, and is left as an interpretation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, "Vertical sum of a binary tree" what is not clear? I have specified values of each vertical line. I'm expecting people to help me by providing algorithm to find that efficiently.

Comment: I have asked a specific question: Why is line 5 the same as 1,3,6, how did you arrive at this. If you feel it should be clear, and do not want to edit your question to specify this, flag it for reopening and another mod might disagree with me. When you draw a typical binary tree, you do not put nodes 3 and 6 (at the bottom) directly below the root, they're either to the left of root, or to the right of root. As such, please clarify the details why you ended up with those specific "vertical lines".

Comment: Additionally, this question is [a duplicate of this: calcuating the sum of nodes in a single verticle line of a binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960104/calcuating-the-sum-of-nodes-in-a-single-verticle-line-of-a-binary-tree), *which has the same questions in the comments*, but in those comments the answer is given. *This* question here, on the other hand, does not. Either way, the question is unclear, *and* a duplicate.

Comment: Here's an explanation: compute the horizontal distance of each node from the root. Horizontal distance: for each left from the root, add -1 and for each right, add +1. Now all nodes with the same horizontal distances from a root fall into one vertical line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should find the positions, you can do this by counting number of left and rights spend to reach specific node:

```
                 1     : l = 0, r = 0
                / \
               /   \
      l=1,r=0 2     3  : l = 0, r = 1.
             / \   / \
     ...    4...5 6...7 ....
```

Simply you can traverse your binary tree and finally calculate `LorR = NumberOfLeft - NumberOfRights` for each node, then group this numbers (by their `LorR` value) together and find each groups sum (print them from most positive to most negative value of `LorR`).

**Update:** This doesn't answers for tree of height more than two, we can fix this problem with little modification in algorithm.

We can see tree as pyramid, each vertex of pyramid has length 1, after each branch remaining part of branch is equal to what passed in latest move, we show this in picture for tree of height 3:

```
                  1
                /  \
               /    \
              /      \
             2        3    upto this we used 1/2 size of pyramid
            / \      / \
           /   \    /   \
           4   5    6    7  upto this we used 1/2 + 1/4 part of pyramid
          / \ / \  / \  / \
         5  9 1  3 6 7 5   5  upto this we used 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 part of pyramid
```

This means in each step we calculate left values by their height (in fact each time multiply of 1/2 will be added to left value, except last time, which is equal to h-1 st value).

So for this case we have: 1 in root is in group 0, 3 in leaf is in group -1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 0, 6 in leaf is in group 1/2 -  1/4 - 1/4 = 0

1 in leaf is in -1/2 + 1/4 - 1/4 = -1/2 and so on.

For preventing from rounding of 1/(2^x) to zero or other problems we can multiply our factors (1/2, 1/4, 1/8,...) to 2<sup>h-1</sup>. In fact in the first case I wrote we can say factors are multiplied by 2<sup>2-1</sup>.

[image: Related Pyramid for tree of height 4]

Comment: Interesting. Checking your algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: I think your algorithm will not work for binary trees with height more than 2.

Comment: I edited answer this works for all cases.

Comment: Can you check your algorithm for trees with height 5.

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan, Just add one row of triangles with edges of size 1/16 (you can do it in corresponding image), It works fine. In fact it's general.

Comment: Also If you think I got true thing about vertical sum, you can edit your question to make it more clear, and others voting to reopen.

Comment: Thanks. Can you make me more clear by providing exactly how you are calculating group for 1 and 3 (leaves). Also what is your time and space complexity. Thanks again.

Comment: You can say your thanks by upvotes, Time and space complexity for creating groups is O(n), because you should visit each number just one time (traverse tree one time) and allocate its group one time (O(n) space). Also each time you traversing path of length `p` to right you will get +p and if you travel to path of length q in left you will get -q, so total group value is +p+(-q) = p-q, also I think I show how to calculate the path length by triangles image, If is not clear tell me what is not clear to clear it.

Comment: I think you have to make some corrections in your answer. I agree with your logic.
If my understanding is correct, group should be something like this,

Level 0:
1 => 0,

Level 1:
2 = -1/2,
3 = 1/2,

Level 2:
4 => -1/2 - 1/4 = -3/4,
5 => -1/2 + 1/4 = -1/4,
6 =>  1/2 - 1/4 =  1/4,
7 =>  1/2 + 1/4 =  3/4,

Level 3:
5 => -1/2 - 1/4 - 1/4 = -1,
9 => -1/2 - 1/4 + 1/4 = -1/2,
1 => -1/2 + 1/4 - 1/4 = -1/2,
3 => -1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 0,
6 =>  1/2 - 1/4 - 1/4 = 0,
7 =>  1/2 - 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2,
5 =>  1/2 + 1/4 - 1/4 = 1/2,
5 =>  1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8779/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-anantha-krishnan)

Comment: This is actually the current algorithm to find the correct nodes with same horizontal distances. Algorithms given on many sites is wrong eg: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-binary-tree-vertical-order-set-2/

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understood moving left is -1, moving right is +1. You can use modified dfs. Here is assume that `add(col, value)` is defined

```
dfs(col, node)
begin
  add(col, node.value)
  if(haveLeft)
     dfs(col-1, left)
  if(haveRight)
     dfs(col+1, right)
end
```

Assuming, that add works in O(1) (using HashMap or simple array for example), this works in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method in pseudocode:

```
columnAdd(tree):
  sumPerColumn = new Map<int,int>();
  traverse(tree.root, sumPerColumn, 0);
  return sumPerColumn;

traverse(node, sumPerColumn, currentColumn):
  sumPerColumn[currentColumn] ++;
  traverse(node.left, sumPerColumn, currentColumn-1);
  traverse(node.right, sumPerColumn, currentColumn+1);
```

this would yield:

```
  {-2: 4,
   -1: 2,
    0: 12,
    1: 3,
    2: 7}
```

Comment: I think you meant `currentColumn - 1` and `currentColumn + 1`, not `--` and `++`.

Comment: @svick: Yes, that is probably clearer and 'more correct' :). I'll change it.